# Inneractive ad integration error in xml file

Tags: android

Im trying to integrate inner-active to my app .. i downloaded sample project but getting error in xml file...

```
 Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'adType' in package        'com.inneractive.api.ads.sample'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'refreshInterval' in package 
     'com.inneractive.api.ads.sample'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'keywords' in package 
     'com.inneractive.api.ads.sample'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'appID' in package         'com.inneractive.api.ads.sample'
```

XML

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.inneractive.api.ads.InneractiveAd
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        xmlns:inneractive="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.inneractive.api.ads.sample"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        inneractive:appID="Android_IA_Test"
        inneractive:adType="Banner"
        inneractive:keywords="android,test"
        inneractive:refreshInterval="120"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />
```

BTW is that a right choice to go with inner-active for native android apps? TIA

Comment: @Nirit pls help me on this problem

Answer (score 0):

the issue is due to line

`xmlns:inneractive="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.inneractive.api"`

can try as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <view class="com.inneractive.api.ads.InneractiveAd"
        android:id="@+id/ad"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        inneractive:appID="Android_IA_Test"
        inneractive:adType="Banner"
        inneractive:keywords="android,test"
        inneractive:refreshInterval="120"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: refer this http://kevindion.com/2011/01/custom-xml-attributes-for-android-widgets/

Comment: as inneractive: is a custom attribute which is not come with android SDK so you need to follow the procedure to add custom attribute in XML

Comment: hey can you pls notify my question to Mr.Nirit(inner-active officer) pls.. i cant comment anywhere pls....

Answer (score 0):

My name is Nirit and I'm a support manager at Inneractive.

Are you trying to compile our sample app? or your own project?

Please make sure you set "xmlns:inneractive" to be your application package.
In addition, please notice that the `attrs.xml` file (InneractiveAdSample\res\values\attrs.xml) should be added to your project.

If you have any questions or comments please feel free to contact me via the "Contact Support" link on your Dashboard. Best Regards, Nirit.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using inneractive for about 6 month now, and managed to generate decent amount of revenues every month (around $1500 each month). 
It all depends on the amount of downloads that you have and the way you have placed the banners. Don't make it too intrusive for the user but make sure they actually see it and able to click on it.